# Maintain the favorite button state inside collection view

Tags: swift, state, favorites

I have a favorites button inside collection view.
The button shows one image when it is selected and shows another when clicked again.
I want to maintain the image state even if it goes to another view controller and returns back.
the code below is written inside cellforitem of collection view

```
cell.favBtn.tag = indexPath.row
            let value = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSaved")
            print("value is",value)
              cell.favBtn.isSelected = value
               cell.favBtn.isSelected = false
        cell.favBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favBtnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

The favBtnAction function code is as follows:

```
 @IBAction func favBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if objcell.favBtn.isSelected {
                   // set selected

             sender.setImage(image1, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            objcell.favBtn.isSelected = false
                   UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isSaved")
                   UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
               } else {

                   // set deselected
                 sender.setImage(image2, for: UIControl.State.normal)
                  objcell.favBtn.isSelected = true
                   UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isSaved")
                   UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

               }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  struct Record{
    let id:Int
    //your other data
    var isFavourite:Bool

    mutating func setIsFavourite(isFavourite:Bool){
        self.isFavourite = isFavourite
    }
}

let items:[Record] = [] //Your collection view data list is here
```

assign the item id to favourite button tag in cellForItemAt

```
@IBAction func favBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.isSelected{//<- this is how you identify the it is selected or deselected.I add dummy logic here
        items[sender.tag].setIsFavourite(isFavourite: true)
    }else{
        items[sender.tag].setIsFavourite(isFavourite: false)
    }
}
```

Now you use the isFavorite value to display the different images on **cellForItemAt**